# Is it possible to calculate a percentage of the auto width?

Tags: css, width, percentage

I'm pretty new to web dev, and am still learning the boundaries of CSS. I've found one thing that google searches haven't helped me with yet, wondering if anyone here can help me.

I have a navigation bar that I'd like to stretch across the page, with equal padding size/spacing in between each item in the bar. Of course, when the user changes the size of the window, the padding size will increase/decrease accordingly. My nav container is 100% the width of the page, but the nav itself is moved (margin-left) 200px right to leave way for the logo of the site. I figured that I could keep the padding accurate by calculating (since there are 6 items, with 5 empty spaces between them) 20% of the auto width of the website, which would keep a padding flexible with that margin entered. Is this possible? I've seen that it can be done with Javascript, but I'm hoping to avoid that route, since I haven't learned JS yet and have the deadline for this site coming up. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Why are you not just trying this?

Comment: I have been, but don't know how to input it. Tried as a calc() function.

Comment: have a look at my fiddle mate, then we can work on it some more

Comment: why not use box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 0):

something like this mate? http://jsfiddle.net/vjT86/

my solution also uses:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

so might wanna check compatibility for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do without an actual code sample, but here's my best attempt to replicate/fix your issue based off of your description:

http://jsfiddle.net/EK8tL/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#title {
    width: 160px;
    height: inherit;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:blue;
}

#nav {
    list-style: none;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    width: 20%;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: pink;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;

}
```

If you use display: table, you can get get away with using remaining space in instances where it's (probably) better to just use some javascript, or position things differently altogether.

In the example I provided, the title div will stay the same size, and the nav will scale to fill the remaining space to the right of it. Of course if you do it like this, you have to manually change the li width % to match the number of list items.

I apologize if this isn't what you were looking for, it's just hard to tell from your description.